# what is Off in IDA Pro?

Tags: ida, malware

probably silly question, what does Off ... means in IDA Pro?
i markered the snapshot as an example.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You might have a look [here](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/609.shtml) It says:

```
off_          data, contains offset value
```

Comment: Thanks Josh,    
offset value from where to where.

Comment: To my experience, _off indicates a 32-bit pointer (in x32 world), thus being rather misleading in case you except some address offset. The _off name might have its origin in the segmented addressing introduced by Intel many years ago in their 16-bit times (segment:offset), today being rather obsolete because of the flat memory model also being used in the Intel world. BTW, just discovered that your question is a duplicate of this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50908226/what-do-prefixes-like-byte-or-off-mean-before-a-hex-value, offering a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Thank you so much.